# Ansible : Select inventory file out of multiple hosts.ini for three environments based on the version passed as a variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-tower

I have a task , in which I need to select the target environment/hosts amongst the multiple inventory files placed in different folders under inventories/ directory. The selection is based on the version passed as a variable.

```
inventories/
           preprod/
                  group_vars/
                  hosts.ini
                  ...
           systest/
                  group_vars/
                  hosts.ini
                  ...
           uat/
                  group_vars/
                  hosts.ini
                  ...
```

So if the version varaiable is 1.x.x  then the hosts.ini under preprod should be selected, if its 2.x.x then the hosts.ini under systest should be selected and if its 3.x.x the hosts.ini under uat should be selected.

```
---
- name: Select hosts from multiple inventories based on version passed as a variable
  hosts: all
  vars:
    version: '1.0'
  tasks:
  - name: Get hosts from first inventory
    set_fact:
      hosts_1: "{{ groups['inventory_1'] | selectattr('version', 'equalto', version) | map(attribute='hostname') | list }}"
  - name: Get hosts from second inventory
    set_fact:
      hosts_2: "{{ groups['inventory_2'] | selectattr('version', 'equalto', version) | map(attribute='hostname') | list }}"
  - name: Merge hosts from both inventories
    set_fact:
      hosts: "{{ hosts_1 + hosts_2 }}"
  - name: Run tasks with hosts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ hosts }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Copy the inventory file in the first play, [*refresh_inventory*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html#ansible-builtin-meta-module-execute-ansible-actions), and use it in the second play. Unfortunately, this does not refresh *group_vars* from the directories. As a workaround put the *group_vars* into the inventory files.

Details: Given the project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts.env
├── inventory
│   ├── preprod
│   │   └── hosts.ini
│   ├── systest
│   │   └── hosts.ini
│   └── uat
│       └── hosts.ini
└── pb.yml

4 directories, 6 files
```

Put the *group_vars* into the inventory files

```ini
shell> cat inventory/preprod/hosts.ini 
[all]
preprod1
preprod2
preprod3

[all:vars]
env_gv=preprod
```

```ini
shell> cat inventory/systest/hosts.ini 
systest1
systest2
systest3

[all:vars]
env_gv=systest
```

```ini
shell> cat inventory/uat/hosts.ini 
[all]
uat1
uat2
uat3

[all:vars]
env_gv=uat
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    envs:
      1: preprod
      2: systest
      3: uat
    env: "{{ envs[version.split('.').0|int] }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Use environment: {{ env }}"
    - copy:
        src: "{{ playbook_dir }}/inventory/{{ env }}/hosts.ini"
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/hosts.env"
    - meta: refresh_inventory

- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - block:
        - debug:
            var: ansible_play_hosts_all
        - debug:
            var: env_gv
      run_once: true
```

gives

**version=1.0** works in the environment **preprod**

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts.env -e version=1.0 pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: 'Use environment: preprod'

TASK [copy] *********************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [meta] *********************************************************************************************

PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [preprod1] => 
  ansible_play_hosts_all:
  - preprod1
  - preprod2
  - preprod3

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [preprod1] => 
  env_gv: preprod

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
preprod1: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**version=2.0** works in the environment **systest**

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts.env -e version=2.0 pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: 'Use environment: systest'

TASK [copy] *********************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [meta] *********************************************************************************************

PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [systest1] => 
  ansible_play_hosts_all:
  - systest1
  - systest2
  - systest3

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [systest1] => 
  env_gv: systest

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
systest1: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**version=3.0** works in the environment **uat**

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts.env -e version=3.0 pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: 'Use environment: uat'

TASK [copy] *********************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [meta] *********************************************************************************************

PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [uat1] => 
  ansible_play_hosts_all:
  - uat1
  - uat2
  - uat3

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [uat1] => 
  env_gv: uat

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
uat1: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

**Example. Precedence of *group_vars*. YAML format.**

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── group_vars
│   └── all.yml
├── hosts
├── inventories
│   ├── preprod
│   │   └── hosts
│   ├── systest
│   │   └── hosts
│   └── uat
│       └── hosts
├── inventory
│   ├── group_vars
│   │   └── all.yml
│   └── hosts
└── pb.yml

7 directories, 9 files
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all.yml 
env_gv3: playbook group_vars/all
```

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/group_vars/all.yml 
env_gv2: inventory group_vars/all
```

```yaml
shell> cat inventories/preprod/hosts 
all:
  hosts:
    preprod1:
    preprod2:
    preprod3:
  vars:
    env_gv1: preprod1 inventory file group_vars
    env_gv2: preprod2 inventory file group_vars
    env_gv3: preprod3 inventory file group_vars
```

```yaml
shell> cat inventories/systest/hosts 
all:
  hosts:
    systest1:
    systest2:
    systest3:
  vars:
    env_gv1: systest1 inventory file group_vars
    env_gv2: systest2 inventory file group_vars
    env_gv3: systest3 inventory file group_vars
```

```yaml
shell> cat inventories/uat/hosts 
all:
  hosts:
    uat1:
    uat2:
    uat3:
  vars:
    env_gv1: uat1 inventory file group_vars
    env_gv2: uat2 inventory file group_vars
    env_gv3: uat3 inventory file group_vars
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    envs:
      1: preprod
      2: systest
      3: uat
    env: "{{ envs[version.split('.').0|int] }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Use environment: {{ env }}"
    - copy:
        src: "{{ playbook_dir }}/inventories/{{ env }}/hosts"
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/inventory/hosts"
    - meta: refresh_inventory

- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - block:
        - debug:
            var: ansible_play_hosts_all
        - debug:
            msg: |
              env_gv1: {{ env_gv1 }}
              env_gv2: {{ env_gv2 }}
              env_gv3: {{ env_gv3 }}
      run_once: true
```

```bash
shell> ansible-playbook -i inventory/hosts -e version=2.0 pb.yml
```

shows that [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence):

3. inventory file or script group vars
4. inventory group_vars/all
5. playbook group_vars/all

works as expected

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: 'Use environment: systest'

TASK [copy] *********************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [meta] *********************************************************************************************

PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [systest1] => 
  ansible_play_hosts_all:
  - systest1
  - systest2
  - systest3

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [systest1] => 
  msg: |-
    env_gv1: systest1 inventory file group_vars
    env_gv2: inventory group_vars/all
    env_gv3: playbook group_vars/all

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
systest1: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks for you response Vladimir. That is very helpful.

Comment: Just to be Sure, 
We have multiple yml files inside the group_vars , So we can include contents of each file inside the host.ini file under different groups without affecting the results. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes. This should work. What's inside the file *host.ini* ( or inside the file *hosts.env* in the above example) will be refreshed by *`meta: refresh_inventory`*. You might want to change the format to *host.yaml*. It's easier to declare the variables in YAML.